# Will GeoIP based personalization rules work in Sitecore 10 if Tracking is disabled?

Tags: personalization, geo-location

Will *GeoIP* based personalization rules work in case Tracking is disabled in code like `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Enabled = false` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tracking needs to be enabled in order to use GeoIP, if you take a look at the Sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/enable-disable-the-xdb-and-the-tracker.html it is specified that if tracker is disabled the `IP Geolocation services` are unavailable on both CM and CD
[image]